# How to convert a date into another date as a String in Java?

Tags: java, spring, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

I want to convert a date format into another date format. For example, I have this String "05-Apr-23" and I want to convert it into this String "05/04/23". And I did this implementation but it's not working.

```
String oldDate = "05-Apr-23";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yy");
Date dt = null;
try {
    dt = sdf.parse(oldDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new CustomInternalServerException(oldDate + "is not a valid date");
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
return sdf1.format(dt);
```

I get the exception ParseException: UnparseableDate: "05-Apr-23". Any feedback will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You probably mean MMM (long month), not mmm (long minutes?!)

Comment: Yes this is the month like Apr for April.

Comment: Don't use superseded date classes. `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` - no! `LocalDate` `DateTimeFormatter` - yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did only one small mistake you have to use MMM instead of mmm , m is used for minute and M is for month.

change as follow

```
dd-mmm-yy to dd-MMM-yy
dd/mm/yy to dd/MM/yy
```

and one more mistake at last you have to return sdf1 not sdf.

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

Don't use superseded date classes. `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` - no! `LocalDate` , `DateTimeFormatter` - yes!

And the formatting pattern is case-sensitive. For abbreviated name of month, use uppercase ‘MMM’.

Specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to be used in determining the human language and cultural norms for localizing that name of month.

```
String oldDate = "05-Apr-23";
DateTimeFormatter dfFrom = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy").withLocale( Locale.US );
DateTimeFormatter dfTo = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy");
String newDate = dfTo.format(LocalDate.parse(oldDate, dfFrom));
System.out.println(newDate);
```

Comment: Wondered about the `Locale` - wasn't sure

Comment: BTW there is also a 2-argument `ofPattern(String, Locale)`...

Comment: Thank you for explanation! But what exactly does this Locale refer to? For example if the application is used in Bulgaria, there is no Locale.Bulgary or something like this...

Comment: @elvis You are expected to do some basic research before posting here on Stack Overflow. (a) Read [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html). (b) Read the relevant section of *The Java Tutorials* provided free of cost by Oracle Corp: [*Lesson: Setting the Locale*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/index.html). There you will find four ways to create a `Locale` object.

Comment: [`Locale.forLangaugeTag("bg_BG")`](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/bg-BG/index.html). Your search engine will find this and other locales easily.